# Upgraded to ActiveAdmin 1.0. Getting error undefined method `exclude_contest_eq' for Ransack::Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I just upgraded to rails 4 and ActiveAdmin 1.0.  I'm having problem with page that won't work anymore.  Here is the error:

```
undefined method `exclude_contest_eq' for Ransack::Search<class: Project, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

Here is where the code is failing

```
controller do
  def render(*args)
    @projects.uniq! if @projects and action_name == 'index'
    super(*args)
  end
end
```

What has changed that is throwing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with filtering.
[Here is the thread](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2565) with long discussion of the issue.

The essence of it, that quickest fix would be, probably, to add `remove_filter :exclude_contest` to the model definition.

May this will solve your problem as well.